# ASP.NET MVC 4 database scaffolding self referential model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-migrations

I have a constructed a model using code first in C#. The model literally represents a container element for a website building application, in other words,  the model defines a Div tag or some such HTML element. Like a Div tag which can contain multiple child elements, I have tried to represent this in my model, but the scaffolding to the DB, does not give me what I'd expect.

I should get a new many to many joins table, but instead I only get a single column in the DB which expects a single int data type.

Here is the model:

```
 public class ElementContainer
{
    public int ElementContainerID { get; set; }
    public int PageId { get; set; }
    public int? ParentElementContainerID { get; set; }
    public string ElementContainerName { get; set; }
    public ElementType ElementType { get; set; }
    public string ElementClass { get; set; }
    public PageAsset PageAsset { get; set; } // content of container

    public List<ElementContainer> NestedContainers { get; set; }
}
```

The last line is the self-referential attribute which just appears as a column called ElementContainer_ElementContainerID

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I usually use database first (just temporary) for complicated entities to get the code and use the generated code in my applications. Because creating the relationships in DB is much easier than EF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Bahman, DB first is easier.

While I haven't tried to do what you are trying, your code looks like a self-Join that would do exactly what you describe.

This is a One-to-Many relationship. EF Navigation will pull a List of all nested children containers.

If you want to create a many-to-many relationship with EF Code-First, you should create another Entity

```
 public class ContainerChildren
{
    public int ElementContainerID { get; set; }
    public List<ElementContainer> NestedContainers { get; set; }
}
```

this reference should help you to get the exact idea http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2011/05/14/code-first-ef-4-1-building-many-to-many-relationship.aspx

Comment: Thanks. It turns out that it is a many-to-one so I was incorrect to begin with. But this does help understand how to create a many to many relationship - thanks!